# When are delegates and Func/Action not interchangeable?

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

In most cases delegates and Func/Action are interchangeable, but is there cases where they're not interchangeable? Is there some subtle differences in capabilities?

(Yes, there's a lot of "Action vs Delegates" on SO, but none answer the question of capabilities and when they're not interchangeable.)

By "cases where they're not interchangeable" I mean cases where you can't just literally replace Func into corresponding delegate (and delegate into corresponding Func).

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by interchangable? Note that `Func`/`Action` *are* delegates, so it's not clear what you're talking about... an example would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It's still not at all clear - what do you mean by "corresponding delegate"? `Func<TResult>` *is* a delegate. A concrete example *in code* would be much more helpful - currently the question still sounds like you're missing the fact that `Func<TResult>` is a delegate type

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, I believed that Func/Action where classes encapsulating delegates, but they literally are delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet answered in the comments, I was missing the fact that Action/Func are literally delegates (I thought it was classes encapsulating delegates) :

```
namespace System
{
    public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
}
```

So there's no difference between delegates and corresponding Func/Action because Func/Action are delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Func and Action are not interchangeable at all

1. `Func`  and `Action` are both delegates
2. `Func<T,TResult>` should always return  a value
3. `Action<T>` should never return  a value